# Installing QuantLib Python under Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, quantlib, quantlib-swig

I am trying to install QuantLib Python under Windows. I dowloaded [Christopher Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) precompiled version 3.5 64-bit and installed it, but got usual error after running it

```
File "E:/Code/Centerprise/Positions/Common items/Python/Temp.py", line 4, in <module>
    from QuantLib import *
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\QuantLib\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .QuantLib import *
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\QuantLib\QuantLib.py", line 28, in <module>
    _QuantLib = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\QuantLib\QuantLib.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_QuantLib', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Then I downloaded and installed QuantLib SWIG and ran 
    python setup.py install

And received back:

error: Unable to find vsvarsall.bat

I read more about it and it looks like I need to download and install Visual Studio 2015.

Is there simpler solution? Downloading and installing VS 2015 means manual compiling if I understand correctly.

**Update**

I was able to solve the problem by downloading [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48145). This is all mentioned on Christopher Gohlke web-site. I should have read more carefully. Christopher is awesome man, on the other hand, it is horrible idea to rely on only one man's work.